# Accept-Encoding and range not working together

Tags: apache2

I need to get Cloud Optimised Geotiff from an Apache server.

Now, if I test it issueing from console:

`curl "path_to_TIF" -H 'accept:*/*' -H 'range:bytes=0-1' --output test.tif`

I correctly get the two bytes I'm asking in the `range` header request and indeed, doing the request via javascript, I correcly see the `206` status code, but if I add to the `curl`

`-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, identity'`

I get the full file instead of just 2 bytes (via javascript I still get `206` status).

What is that is causing this? Could it be that `accept-encoding` is not enabled in Apache? Am I barking at the wrong tree?